# Setting two widgets side by side with scrollbars using TkInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**Scenario:** I have two long series of strings of text that should be displayed side-by-side for comparison. I am trying to use TkInter to paste both and a vertical scrollbar to each and a single horizontal scrollbar that moves both at once.

**Issue:** I was able to insert the contents side by side in two different widgets and was able to insert a vertical scrollbar to both. But I am having trouble inserting one horizontal scrollbar that scroll both widgets at the same time

**Code so far:**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

S1 = tk.Scrollbar(root)
template1 = tk.Text(root, height=100, width=100)
S1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
template1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
template1.config(yscrollcommand=S1.set)
template1.insert(tk.END, file1data)

S2 = tk.Scrollbar(root)
template2 = tk.Text(root, height=100, width=100)
S2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
template2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
template2.config(yscrollcommand=S2.set)
template2.insert(tk.END, file2data)

S3 = tk.Scrollbar(root)
template3 = tk.Text(root, height=100, width=100)
S3.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
template3.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
template3.config(xscrollcommand=S3.set)
template3.insert(tk.END)

tk.mainloop()
```

**Data example** (both file1data and file2data are just long strings life this):

```
file1data = {qUdYzh5H5ilpZZQ6gFklTt3JFy8rTy2QSGQip0blDWj18VIkxBEAHTL18xf1S1tGbmvb0laqYx1gTsrDa3nnkTR6KstOWvJiWpY4v308Mtw5NIEq8sYRt0mFoR0WzHVvak7RmOHR0v3VijwfPRGBq93nIsTxGJVuvWYnPGUDXciuS650s6pbdOtzKaSKaWf2jFFAIBEgwpWNTrQSLkKgg0h5eA8IYdnrrroXsak3Oiq3asU7tThnUPps1rRl2oXe
8e0ZxkWL34kjB1cX3lGae7ixys7nRUQJYiFWUeVsE19u31gPxxy5mzrf9bgkP055Dk5Oquwyeg0tWBsIeMatJd1cgm5cbsgXwM0wuBjeKTFg6MCWQCSFrUpVlr0Uz3ZNEOCDKVePhGDSOJnNbe6Qvx41GeDIRBXdVw12PrD8QWAGK2OPQ5FfwgObBmMV3cEYlQJGNgXowTICaUfNQRfpuGN5CnoksIQ4E4MaOv13dnIpUPXWc3QCu1bf3cmhNoUP
rXcxVi7ZkJ8AtvtRrdZSNUU34msnNrFIPNBoJmqkZTr7E3QCMHyMfZbVQwaThO5q1OCfOA2oZ26VZHzZamTXGleHVXoARH0OQ0XFZsYwwz8tnWqtPuAzAVcjJtdUNxrPbKFlPei1MzschurpyvTwe9pi86oKp1P72XDUhnvJ3kAfRj1kjxSeQFEGX28Op0PtOzoc2taGlgyLO5THiLruSnLNBVKZMt9wBefu4vtjB8riD7itodprVoT960YlDGgQ
dY93hAPuyb8O6qn3olYbrm0Hp65XpSRZoWjo09XhEjVbC7chDWoUWjcrqMVZibcwxAx4HOHJgUrL3QU10U3FQP0JvYCTJkdR5OxLQCWrBCylU43FNEUuGgqnyPWH6nADtI6euwHpFowX4SfMKXBzdWv7ROuJ6QMxypYwo2wLA7yy9AaimVZOfFOnXwd7GNsYGfM4Cdsq4I0WsSgJLUPQeQTj5Xs8E9sp8Y8ykOHSebI7frQagRKgwRAUila0ERBn}
```

**Question:** How could I do this multi-widget single scrollbar?

Comment: what does "having trouble" mean? What sort of trouble are you having? Does the scrollbar appear in the wrong place? Does it only scroll one widget? Does it scroll both, but at the wrong amount? Does your program crash? ...

Comment: @BryanOakley It does not appear at all. And my vertical scrollbars only scroll by clicks, If I try to drag them, they go back to the beginning.

Comment: Your description mentions two text widgets, your code shows three. Also, your description mentions a horizontal scrollbar but I only see three vertical scrollbars.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was trying to set up the horizontal scrollbar in the third part.

Comment: What's the third text widget for?

Comment: @BryanOakley I was trying to set up the scrollbar there. There is no content, just the scrollbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In standard Tkinter, these methods and options have standard names;
>   the scrollbar should call the widget’s xview or yview method when the
>   scrollbar is changed, and the widgets provide xscrollcommand and
>   yscrollcommand command options that are called when the scrollbar
>   needs to be updated.

read more here: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm

scrollbar needs to call a function that calls the `yview` method of your two widgets:

```
def viewall(*args):
    template1.yview(*args)
    template2.yview(*args)

S4 = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=viewall)
S4.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
```

EDIT: two text widget's scrolling synchronized - HORIZONTAL

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

file1data = ("qUdYzh5H5ilpZZQ6gFklTt3JFy8rTy2QSGQip0blDWj18VIkxBEAHTL1\n8xf1S1tGbmvb0laqYx1gTsrDa3nnkTR6KstOWvJiWpY4v308Mtw5NIEq8sYRt0mFoR0WzHVvak7RmOHR0v3VijwfPRGBq93nIsTxGJVuvWYnPGUDXciuS650s6pbdOtzKaSKaWf2jFFAIBEgwpWNTrQSLkKgg0h5eA8IYdnrrroXsak3Oiq3asU7tThnUPps1rRl2oXe8e0ZxkWL34kjB1cX3lGae7ixys7nRUQJYiFWUeVsE19u31gPxxy5mzrf9bgkP055Dk5Oquwyeg0tWBsIeMatJd1cgm5cbsgXwM0wuBjeKTFg6MCWQCSFrUpVlr0Uz3ZNEOCDKVe\nPhGDSOJnNbe6Qvx41GeDIRBXdVw12PrD8QWAGK2OPQ5FfwgObBmMV3cEYlQJGNgXowTICaUfNQRfpuGN5CnoksIQ4E4MaOv13dnIpUPXWc3QCu1bf3cmhNoUPrXcxVi7ZkJ\n8AtvtRrdZSNUU34msnNrFIPNBoJmqkZTr7E3QCMHyMfZbVQwaThO5q1OCfOA2oZ26VZHzZamTXGleH\nVXoARH0OQ0XFZsYwwz8tnWqtPuAzAVcjJtdUNxrPbKFlPei1MzschurpyvTwe9pi86oKp1P72XDUhnvJ3kAfRj1kjxSeQFEGX28Op0PtOzoc2taGlgyLO5THiLruSnLNBVKZMt9wBefu4vtjB8riD7itodprVoT960YlDGgQdY93hAPuyb8O6qn3olYbrm0Hp65XpSRZoWjo09")

def viewall(*args):
    template1.xview(*args)
    template2.xview(*args)

xscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
xscrollbar.config(command=viewall)

template1 = tk.Text(root, height=50, width=50,wrap=tk.NONE, xscrollcommand = xscrollbar.set)
template1.grid(row=0, column=0)
template1.insert(tk.END, file1data)

template2 = tk.Text(root, height=50, width=50,wrap=tk.NONE, xscrollcommand = xscrollbar.set)
template2.grid(row=0, column=1)
template2.insert(tk.END, file1data)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

======================================

EDIT 2

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

file1data = ("qUdYzh5H5ilpZZQ6gFklTt3JFy8rTy2QSGQip0blDW   j18VIkxBEAHTL1\n8xf1S1tGbmvb0laqYx1gTsrDa3   nnkTR6KstOWvJiWpY4v308Mt  w5NIEq8sYRt0mFoR 0WzHVva  7RmOHR0v3Vi jwfPRG  Bq93nIsTxGJV uvWY nPGUDXciuS650s6pbd OtzKaSKa Wf2jFFAIBEgw   pWNTrQSLk Kgg0h5eA8IYd nrrroXsak3Oiq3asU7tThnUPps1rRl2oXe8e0ZxkWL34kjB1cX3lGae7ixys7nRUQJYiFWUeVsE19u31gPxxy5mzrf9bgkP055Dk5Oquw  yeg0tWBsIeMatJd1cgm5cbsg  XwM0wuBjeKTFg6MCWQCSFrUpVlr0Uz3ZNEOCDKVe\nPhGDSOJnNbe6Qvx41GeDIRBXdVw12PrD8QWAGK2OQ4E4MaOv13dnIpUPXWc3QCu1bf3cmhNoUPrXcxVi7ZkJ\n8AtvtRrdZSNUU34msnNrFIPNBoJmqkZ  Tr7E3QCMHyMfZbVQwaThO5q1OCfOA2oZ26VZHzZamTXGleH\nVXoARH0OQ0XFZsYwwz8tnWqtPuAzAVcjJtdUNxrPbKFlPei1MzschurpyvTwe9pi86oKp1P72XDUhnvJ3kAfRj1kjxSeQFEGX28Op0PtOzoc2taGlgy")

def viewall(*args):
    template1.xview(*args)
    template2.xview(*args)

xscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, columnspan=4, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
xscrollbar.config(command=viewall)

S1 = tk.Scrollbar(root)
S1.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
template1 = tk.Text(root, height=25, width=50,wrap=tk.NONE, xscrollcommand = xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=S1.set)
template1.grid(row=0, column=0)
template1.insert(tk.END, file1data)
S1.config(command=template1.yview)

S2 = tk.Scrollbar(root)
S2.grid(row=0, column=3,sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
template2 = tk.Text(root, height=25, width=50,wrap=tk.NONE, xscrollcommand = xscrollbar.set,yscrollcommand=S2.set)
template2.grid(row=0, column=2)
template2.insert(tk.END, file1data)
S2.config(command=template2.yview)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that works fine for a vertical scrollbar. But my problem is creating an horizontal scrollbar. I tried to modify it, but it does not seem to work the same way.

Comment: That works great to have a horizontal scrollbar for both widgets, so I consider the question answered. But now the other vertical scrollbars do not work for me anymore.